# How to restrict UID range in AD Identity Management for UNIX

Tags: linux, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, uid

I want to enable AD (win 2008 R2) users on a linux box. The problem is that there are also local users (for historical reasons). Now I want to make sure that there is no clash in UIDs (or at least minimise the chance). The historic local accounts are all in a certain range, way below 20000. Is there a way to tell the AD "Identity Management for UNIX" role that UIDs should be above a certain number?

Any other approaches towards the unique UID goal are also welcome :)

Comment: What services? If you're just looking for an integrated login architecture, you might want to check out [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeIPA)

Comment: I want to ssh into the centos client machine, using the AD accounts allready in place. So I am not looking for another directory service.